# Load Javascript when div is in viewport

Tags: javascript, html

Thats the Div in HTML file

```
<div class="inViewport">
```

And this script should be loading only when the div is in viewport

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            ToxProgress.create();
            ToxProgress.animate();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I would load the script as usual, and use the [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to trigger those methods.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you should look at: [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/how-to-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Here is an example for you that demonstrates this technique: http://jsfiddle.net/XYS2G/ - just try to scroll the Result window.

HTML:

```
<div class="indicators">
    <span class="indicator" data-id="section1">section1</span>
    <span class="indicator" data-id="section2">section2</span>
    <span class="indicator" data-id="section3">section3</span>
    <span class="indicator" data-id="section4">section4</span>
    <span class="indicator" data-id="section5">section5</span>
    <span class="indicator" data-id="section6">section6</span>
</div>
<div class="sections">
    <div class="section" id="section1">section1</div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">section2</div>
    <div class="section" id="section3">section3</div>
    <div class="section" id="section4">section4</div>
    <div class="section" id="section5">section5</div>
    <div class="section" id="section6">section6</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.indicators { position: fixed; }
.section { height: 150px; }
```

Javascript:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

function refreshIndicators() {
    $('.indicator').each(function () {
        if (isScrolledIntoView($('#' + $(this).attr('data-id')))) {
            $(this).css('color', 'red');
        } else {
            $(this).css('color', 'black');
        }
    });
}

refreshIndicators();

$(window).bind('scroll', refreshIndicators);
```

Comment: @peter Could you vote my answer with best answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think this function will help you:

```js
function isInViewport(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
}
```

(taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557433/14909980))
Then, you need to listen to the scroll event, and every time the user scrolls, you check if the element is in the viewport by calling above function. Sample:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll resize", function() {
    if (isInViewport(document.getById("inViewport"))) {
       ToxProgress.create();
       ToxProgress.animate();
    }
});
```